# Casablanca C++ Rest SDK - how to disable certificate validation on websocket

Tags: c++, websocket, casablanca

I'm using cpprestsdk v. 2.8.0. I need to disable certificate validation on websocket

```
websocket_client_config wcc;
websocket_client client(wcc);
client.connect(U("wss://192.168.3.45/product/webapiws")).wait();
```

this code give me an exception because the certificate is not valid. 
I need a function like set_validate_certificates, but I don't find it...
I find only set_validate_certificates for http_client_config but not for websocket_client_config.

Is there a way to set validate certificates to false on websocket_client_config?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a year old but as of libcpprest-2.9 the websocket_client_config has a method websocket_client_config::set_validate_certificates(bool) . On a side not you may need to build the library from source depending on what your environment is. I'm working in ubuntu and the default repos only have a a reference to 2.8.2 which does not have this feature.